# Report stopped working on JasperReportsServer after modification of stored procedure

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

We have a report that was running perfectly using the *iReport* designer, and from the *JasperReports Serer*.

I made some minor modifications to the underlying *MySQL* stored procedure, and adjusted the report structure accordingly, and now I can run the report from the Designer interface, but not at all from the server.

I'm receiving an error as follows:

```
Error Message

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

Which I understand to be a problem with one of the dates we use in the report, but none of the date information changed that I am aware of.

I'll start by attaching the report, and the top section of the stored procedure:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_fasb`(start_date varchar(10), end_date     varchar(10), loc varchar(45))
BEGIN
declare friday_end_date varchar(10);
declare in_str varchar(255);

if dayofweek(end_date) = 7 then
  SET friday_end_date = date_add(end_date, interval 6 day);
else
  SET friday_end_date = date_add(end_date, interval (6-dayofweek(end_date)) day);
end if; 

if dayofweek(end_date) = 7 then
SET end_date = date_add(end_date, interval -1 day);
end if;

if dayofweek(end_date) = 1 then
  SET end_date = date_add(end_date, interval -2 day);
end if;
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, all the `date` datatype is `varchar(10)`.

Since you are using date_add functions, you cannot have your 'start_date'  as a string.

When you try this on MYSQL

```
SELECT date_add(curdate(), interval 6 day);
Result:2013-05-06
```

But when you try

```
SELECT date_add('2013-04-30', interval 6 day);
```

`You do not get any result or you get 'BLOB'` which means it is expecting a  variable of Date datatype inside the funcation.

Also in your report, may be you have your input parameter defined as java.util.Date.
You may want to change that and see if this is a problem with input parameter.
This could also be a problem.

Hope this helps.!

Comment: Thank you, I understand how that was causing an issue, and made the recommended changes.  The report still failed on the server, and here's what I found:  At some point last week, I must have made the change to text fields trying to fix something that I broke earlier.  When that failed to fix the report, I deleted the report from the server and tried re-uploading it....THAT is where the real problems began, because I failed to relink the Input Controls.  Once I applied your suggestion AND relinked the Input Controls, it works perfectly...Thank you again...

Comment: No Problem.If my answer help you resolve your query,you may want to accept the answer since it might help others in future with similar issues.